# Console.ReadKey() not working

Tags: c#, .net

Please look at [original Microsoft example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd997306(v=vs.110).aspx).

In the second example we find the following code:

```
// The simplest UI thread ever invented.
Task.Run(() =>
{
    if (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar == 'c')
        cts.Cancel();
});
```

(Full code needed to run this:)

```
static int inputs = 2000;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // The token source for issuing the cancelation request.
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    // A blocking collection that can hold no more than 100 items at a time.
    BlockingCollection<int> numberCollection = new BlockingCollection<int>(100);

    // Set console buffer to hold our prodigious output.
    //Console.SetBufferSize(80, 2000);

    // The simplest UI thread ever invented.
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        if (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar == 'c')
            cts.Cancel();
        else
        {
            Debugger.Break();
        }
    });

    // Start one producer and one consumer.
    Task.Run(() => NonBlockingConsumer(numberCollection, cts.Token));
    Task.Run(() => NonBlockingProducer(numberCollection, cts.Token));

    Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void NonBlockingConsumer(BlockingCollection<int> bc, CancellationToken ct)
{
    // IsCompleted == (IsAddingCompleted && Count == 0)
    while (!bc.IsCompleted)
    {
        int nextItem = 0;
        try
        {
            if (!bc.TryTake(out nextItem, 0, ct))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Take Blocked");
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine(" Take:{0}", nextItem);
        }

        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Taking canceled.");
            break;
        }

        // Slow down consumer just a little to cause
        // collection to fill up faster, and lead to "AddBlocked"
        Thread.SpinWait(500000);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\r\nNo more items to take. Press the Enter key to exit.");
}

static void NonBlockingProducer(BlockingCollection<int> bc, CancellationToken ct)
{
    int itemToAdd = 0;
    bool success = false;

    do
    {
        // Cancellation causes OCE. We know how to handle it.
        try
        {
            // A shorter timeout causes more failures.
            success = bc.TryAdd(itemToAdd, 2, ct);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Add loop canceled.");
            // Let other threads know we're done in case
            // they aren't monitoring the cancellation token.
            bc.CompleteAdding();
            break;
        }

        if (success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Add:{0}", itemToAdd);
            itemToAdd++;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write(" AddBlocked:{0} Count = {1}", itemToAdd.ToString(), bc.Count);
            // Don't increment nextItem. Try again on next iteration.

            //Do something else useful instead.
            UpdateProgress(itemToAdd);
        }

    } while (itemToAdd < inputs);

    // No lock required here because only one producer.
    bc.CompleteAdding();
}

static void UpdateProgress(int i)
{
    double percent = ((double)i / inputs) * 100;
    Console.WriteLine("Percent complete: {0}", percent);
}
```

What that code should do is totally clear: it should break on pressing `c`, but it doesn't work. Instead it runs until the end asking to close with `Enter`.

How can we fix this?

It seems to be a threading problem, but it's a demo for .net4.5 and the code is not working.

The KeyPress of 'c' does not set the CancelationToken.

Comment: In what way does it not work? Have you debugged?

Comment: Have you pressed any other key befoce 'c' ?

Comment: @Fabrizio no, I don't touch the Keyboard before.

Comment: I expect this to exit immediately without waiting for input, because it is not blocking the main thread.

Comment: amazes me how he's got a valid question and people just downvote away

Comment: @Ramie the initial question was unclear and only referring to an online resource for the code to reproduce. I understand people voted like this. That is why I edited it and I think it is fine now.

Comment: @PatrickHofman he provided a link to the full code on the MSDN site, I assumed people clicked the link to get what he was talking about

Comment: Indeed. And that shouldn't be necessary. A question here should stand on its own. What if MS changes (fixes) the code? That this question renders invalid. Now it remains valid.

Comment: Thank you for your question [Andy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1398504/greeneyedandy) and thanks [Patrick](http://stackoverflow.com/users/993547/patrick-hofman) for providing the solution and submitting the feedback to our topic on MSDN. I have updated the latest version of the [English topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997306(v=vs.110).aspx) with the suggested fix and also fixed the Visual Basic sample that was all broken. However, the updated localized version of this topic will show up later on the library (mentioning that since I noticed you were pointing to the German v

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are totally right on the example being wrong. It is just broken.

The reason it doesn't work is that it doesn't wait on the completion of the `Task`s, instead it waits on the `Console.ReadLine`. This will fix it:

Replace:

```
Task.Run(() => NonBlockingConsumer(numberCollection, cts.Token));
Task.Run(() => NonBlockingProducer(numberCollection, cts.Token));
```

With:

```
Task t1 = Task.Run(() => NonBlockingConsumer(numberCollection, cts.Token));
Task t2 = Task.Run(() => NonBlockingProducer(numberCollection, cts.Token));

Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
```

Comment: This is weird. I tried exactly this, but it doesn't work. Now I typed it again, and it's working. Thank you for that.

Comment: Glad it helped you. I posted some feedback on the US MSDN site in order to point them to this question so they can fix it.

Comment: And the error is that the `ReadLine()` is blocking the `ReadKey()` in the Thread?

Comment: Indeed. The last line is meant to be synchronous. If they would have waited on the result of the previous tasks, that call wouldn't block the `ReadKey`.